# Where is my webpack config file in angular 2 cli?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

This is the config that I have on my angular 2 project

```
 ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
node: 6.2.0
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 2.4.8
@angular/compiler: 2.4.8
@angular/core: 2.4.8
@angular/forms: 2.4.8
@angular/http: 2.4.8
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.2
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.8
@angular/router: 3.4.8
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.8
```

Anyway, I couldn't find the webpack file config in anywhere.
Simply, it shouldn't exit or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Look into this. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hidden by default. You can extract it with [`ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) command

> Ejects your app and output the proper webpack configuration and scripts.

I believe you app won't work with CLI anymore, but you can use generated config/scripts as an alternative build solution.

Backup your project before trying  (;

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate. Well, I don't want to modify but at least just to have a keep on it in order to go deeper with ng2. I would do a backup :) thanks for scare me heh

Answer (score -1):

Check in tsconfig.json, probably there is what you looking for.